# Problems with template matching and pyrDown

Tags: node.js, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to make a normal template matching search more effizient by first doing the search on downscaled representations of the image. Basically I do a double pyrDown -> quarter resolution.
For most images and templates this works beautifully, but for some others I get really bad matching results. It seems to be especially bad for thin fonts or small contrast.

Look at this example:

[image: example screenshot]

And this template:

[image]

At 100% resolution I get a matching probability of 99,9%

At 50% resolution I get 90%

At 25% resolution I get 87%

I don't really know why its so bad for some images/templates. I tried to recreate and test in photoshop by hiding/showing the 25% downscaled template on top of the 25% downscaled image, and as you can see, it's not 100% congruent:
https://giphy.com/gifs/coWDjcvHysKgn95IFa

I need a way to get more probability for those matchings at low resolution because it needs to be fast.
Any ideas on how to improve my algorithm?

Here are the original files:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/llbdj9bx5eprxbk/images.zip?dl=0

Comment: You expect to find the template in a certain ROI (Region Of Interest) on the source image, right? For example, you definitely DON’T expect it to find it on the lower portion of the source image, where the icons are. To optimize a little bit you can crop the source to have a smaller size. Are you running the matching on RGB, grayscale or binary images?

Comment: @eldesgraciado I am running it on RGB. Unfortunately I don't know where the ROI is. Could be the bottom as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is not unusual and those scores seem perfectly fine. However here are some ideas that might help you improve the situation:

1. You mentioned that it seems to be especially bad for thin fonts. This could be happening because some of the pixels in the lines are being smoothed out or distorted with the Gaussian filter that is applied on pyrDown. It could also be an indication that you have reduced the resolution too much. Unfortunately I think the pyrDown function in OpenCV reduces the resolution by a factor of 2 so it does not give you the ability to fine tune it by other scale factors. Another thing you could try is the instruction resize() with interpolation set to INTER_LINEAR or INTER_CUBIC. The resize() function will allow you to resize the image using any scale factor so you might have more control of performance vs accuracy.
2. Use multiple templates of the same objects. If you come to a scene and can only achieve an 87% score, create a template out of that scene. Then add it to a database of templates that are to be utilized. Obviously as the amount of templates increases so does the time it takes to complete the search.
3. The best way to deal with this scenario is to perform an exhaustive match on the highest level of the pyramid then track it down to the lowest level using a reduced search space on lower levels. By exhaustive I mean you will search all rows and all columns across the entire top pyramid level image. You will keep track of the locations (row, col) of the highest matches on the highest level (you are already probably doing that). Then you will multiply those locations by a factor of 2 and perform a restricted search on the next lowest level (ex. 5 x 5 shift centered on the rough location). You keep doing this until you are at the bottom level. This will give you the best overall accuracy and performance. This is also the way most industrial computer vision packages do it.